# How can Kubernetes fail to find the file.csi.azure.com driver on a node where it is registered?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm seeing the following set of warnings and errors when trying to a container in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), after adding a new volume to the configuration:

```
19m         Warning   FailedMount              pod/runner-xxxx-project-821-concurrent-0-5cwua3fq   MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "release-area-volume" : kubernetes.io/csi: mounter.SetUpAt failed to get CSI client: driver name file.csi.azure.com not found in the list of registered CSI drivers
19m         Warning   FailedMount              pod/runner-xxxx-project-821-concurrent-0-5cwua3fq   MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "sdk-volume" : kubernetes.io/csi: mounter.SetUpAt failed to get CSI client: driver name file.csi.azure.com not found in the list of registered CSI drivers
20m         Normal    TaintManagerEviction     pod/runner-xxxx-project-821-concurrent-0-5cwua3fq   Cancelling deletion of Pod glr-exp/runner-xxxx-project-821-concurrent-0-5cwua3fq
19m         Normal    SuccessfulAttachVolume   pod/runner-xxxx-project-821-concurrent-0-5cwua3fq   AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-5ef372c5-ddb2-4675-b7e9-d39bd6d3e89d"
19m         Normal    Pulling                  pod/runner-xxxx-project-821-concurrent-0-5cwua3fq   Pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-8ec04662-servercore21H2"
18m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/runner-xxxx-project-821-concurrent-0-5cwua3fq   Successfully pulled image "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-8ec04662-servercore21H2" in 1.3427122s (1.343252s including waiting)
18m         Normal    Created                  pod/runner-xxxx-project-821-concurrent-0-5cwua3fq   Created container init-permissions
18m         Warning   Failed                   pod/runner-xxxx-project-821-concurrent-0-5cwua3fq   Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: hcs::CreateComputeSystem init-permissions: The parameter is incorrect.: unknown
```

When I `kubectl describe` the node, the CSI driver pod looks to be up and running:

```
Non-terminated Pods:          (3 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 cloud-node-manager-windows-c2ks6    50m (2%)      0 (0%)      50Mi (1%)        512Mi (11%)    27h
  kube-system                 csi-azuredisk-node-win-mn7nz        60m (3%)      0 (0%)      120Mi (2%)       600Mi (13%)    27h
  kube-system                 csi-azurefile-node-win-nl4wk        60m (3%)      0 (0%)      120Mi (2%)       700Mi (16%)    27h
```

How is it possible to get a "driver name x not found" error when the driver is definitely present?

For context, this is a CI job being run from gitlab-runner with the Kubernetes executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by getting the YAML description of the pod gitlab-runner was creating. There were two volumes being mounted on the same drive letter. It turns out, if you set `builds_dir: E:\\`, gitlab-runner will mount an empty directory at `E:`, unless it finds some volume whose `mount_path` exactly matches the `builds_dir`. My mount path was `E:`, without the slash at the end. :/

The main point here is that the errors I saw were caused by an attempt to mount two volumes with the same drive letter. Interestingly, it was not `release-area-volume` or `sdk-volume` that had the duplication. It appears that the drive letter misuse caused the entire driver to error out so badly, that it appeared to Kubernetes that it no longer existed, breaking all other mounts with the same driver.